# Direct Power Regression in Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, regression, solver

I want to obtain the `R^2` values for several pairs of `X v/s Y` data.

It can be easily done in Matlab.

But in excel, I believe one needs to create new columns with logarithmic values or something.
Is there a direct, neat, formulas-based, Matlab-esque way to do this in Excel?

Comment: You are looking for a quick function for `R-Squared` in Excel?

Comment: yes, R-squared for power regression.

Comment: You could use a trendline: http://faculty.tcc.edu/PGordy/Excel/powtrend.pdf

Comment: there are many data-sets. a trendline analysis on each would be cumbersome. The last edit by bonCodigo however, fits the bill. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matalb is the *next generation of Excel* ;) So definitely Excel is dull compared to Matalb. But dont' get demotivated, coz it's still a matrix based (Row,Col) *arena*...

Here is a function to try out:

[`RSQ` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/rsq-function-HP010342863.aspx).

`RSQ(known_y's,known_x's)`

References for different ways:

- [calculate R-square in Excel](http://www.ehow.com/how_5117357_calculate-r_squared.html)

---

Edit:

If you need the logarithmic then you may have to use the following:

`=RSQ(y-range,LN(x-range))`

Comment: If I'm right, the method here would still give an R^2 for linear regression - unless I put extra columns with log-values and do a linear regression on them?

Comment: Well then you are looking for a `logarithmic Regression` not `R^2 linear` aren't you? Please check this [post out](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/520036-logarithmic-regression.html) and [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-excel/excel-r-squared-is-incorrect/1dd48555-5f9e-41db-a0d9-b42d95f85499?msgId=64f0d2f8-dae3-42d8-b543-740c3b6fb890).

Comment: oh well, your last edit settles it. Silly of me to not see it by myself. Thank you! :)

Comment: @OrangeRind I guess I missed out the part you specified in your question: *"create new columns with logarithmic values or something"* ;) Good Luck.